# Append html tag with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a `<span>some text</span>` after `<h2>`. The following `html` is from my content pages.

```
<section id="header-title" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <h2 style="text-align: left;">Create User</h2>
           </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

How to append `html tag` with javascript and jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('<span />', { text: 'Some text' }).insertAfter('h2');
```

This will guarantee that the `span` is always just under the `h2`. Using `append` on the `.row` element will place it as the last element within the `div`, which may not always be after the `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#header-title .row').append('<span />');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekyjL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#header-title div.row').append('<span></span>');
```

or to be more specific

```
$('<span></span>').insertAfter($('#header-title').find("h2:contains('Create User')"));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekyjL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

`$("<span />").insertAfter("h2");`

Comment: This will insert the `span` into the `h2`

Comment: Nope... `"I want to append a <span> after <h2>"`

Comment: Fixed it.  Anyways, this question is getting crowded now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#header-title").find("h2").after($("<span/>", {
    text: "text here"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 $( ".row h2" ).append( "<span>Test</span>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   $('#header-title').find('.row').append($('<span>'))
```